# Visual Studio Include Dll Child Project Header Issue

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, qt5

I had a problem including a dll within visual studio the other day, and thought that I had solved all my problems, it turns out, however, that I did not. My problem is odd, too, because one option works, while the other does not. The behavior I am experiencing is a little strange, but I will try to explain it as best as I can. First, here is some code of my attempts(one of which works) to include a header from the dll I created:

```
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>
/*
    This below works; it seems to be stepping backwards out of the
    project and into the folder of the dll project.
*/
#include "../ArclightFramework/GameWindow.h" // This works.
/*
    Below does not work, even though the path has been set in the
    additional directories field of the project. Oddly, though, I
    do get intellisense for the path the below.
*/
#include "ArclightEngine/ArclightFramework/GameWindow.h" // Does not work.
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    GameWindow f;
    f.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

The first include works perfectly fine, and I can live with basing all my future includes off it. However, does anyone know why the second include does not work? And here is what I mean by "Does not work."

```
1>------ Build started: Project: ArclightEngine, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  main.cpp
1>main.cpp(13): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ArclightEngine/ArclightFramework/GameWindow.h': No such file or directory
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

And here is even a picture of the same mouse over error:
[image]

You see, the strange thing is, I DID include the path to my "Additional import directories"; here is a picture:[image]

And here is that directory, and the full path showing that everything SHOULD be found correctly.
[image]

**My question is quite simple. Why can visual studio not find the include files?**

Update: Here is another picture showing how Intellisense is offering completion of the include path, but again, it does not work afterwards!
[image]

Another update:
Alright, so I tried something new. This time instead of adding the absolute path to the Additional Include field, I added: "$(ProjectDir)../../" Once again, Intellisense offers completion for this path and the headers within it. But it does not recognize the files itself afterwards, but they do exist and the path is perfect. My path, using the macro above, would transform my include path to: `"ArclightEngine/ArclightFramework/BLAH.h"`

Here is a new picture showing the path I included:
[image]

I don't understand what the difference is between what I have done and the path that is working which is `"#include "../ArclightFramework/GameWindow.h""`

ALSO, apparently this include path also works now:

```
"#include "/Users/Krynn/Desktop/ArclightEngine/ArclightEngine/ArclightFramework/GameWindow.h""
```

***TL;DR***
**All I want is to be able to type "#include "ArclightEngine/ArclightFramework/blah.h"**

Comment: @PiotrS. Damn, I put the mark at the wrong place in that picture. The directory starts at /ArclightEngine/ArclightFramework, if you look at the picture above you will see that. So no, your suggestion does not work.

Comment: @PiotrS. And remember, I DO get intellisense for "ArclightEngine/ArclightFramework/GameWindow.h" However, it does not actually link correctly.

Comment: @AlexFarber Please look at the picture I just added.

Comment: @AlexFarber And your comment makes no sense because my files are exactly as you said they should be. Look at the provided path in the 3rd picture down from the top.

Comment: @Alex Farber My apologies if I came off aggressive. It was unintentional. I find this problem to be stupid, and it is causing a great deal of frustration. I also cannot add the log you requested because I just climbed into bed. however I will do this when I wake up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've said a user include is:

```
C:\Users\Krynn\Desktop\ArclightEngine
```

And you're trying to include:

```
"ArclightEngine/ArclightFramework/GameWindow.h"
```

Thus the first path VS will try as you've used quotes rather than angle brackets is:

```
C:\Users\Krynn\Desktop\ArclightEngine\ArclightEngine\ArclightFramework\GameWindow.h
```

Which is simply both paths added together, so that's never going to work.

Hence including:

```
"../ArclightEngine/ArclightFramework/GameWindow.h"
```

Becomes:

```
C:\Users\Krynn\Desktop\ArclightEngine\..\ArclightEngine\ArclightFramework\GameWindow.h
```

Which becomes:

```
C:\Users\Krynn\Desktop\ArclightEngine\ArclightFramework\GameWindow.h
```

Hence this works. So another option should be to include:

```
ArclightFramework\GameWindow.h
```

Update:

Looks like your real problem was that you updated the configuration of "Release Win32" but you where building "Debug Win32" which has different settings. When updating setting that apply to all configurations and platforms (such as include paths) be sure to select "all configurations" and "all platforms" from the combo boxes.

Comment: "Hence this works. So another option should be to include:

ArclightFramework\GameWindow.h" <- This does not work, nor do I receive code completion for it.

Comment: The exact same error persists as above "cannot open source file". Also, please see my updates at the bottom of the original post.

Comment: Please enable this option: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdkef6tk.aspx then compile the single cpp file with ctrl+F7 that has the issue and post the output

Comment: I check marked the option you suggested, made sure I was in the source file where I am trying to use the include, and pressed Ctrl+f7. No new output was seen, but here is what showed up: http://pastebin.com/59CNp0KT

Comment: Somethings not right here, it will show what directories the compiler is looking in for that file

Comment: Perhaps try a rebuild?

Comment: New output with rebuild: http://pastebin.com/MMz08Q9L I have to get ready for work now though, so I can't do anything else until after 9pm tonight.

Comment: Btw is the sln file in top level ArcLightEngine dir? If so you could just try adding $(SolutionDir) to your includes

Comment: Also I think I see your problem, you've enabled options in Release Win32, but you are building Debug Win32...

Comment: WE HAVE A HIT! That worked! All I did was change debug to release and blam, my classes turned blue as confirmation. Here is also the output of the build: http://pastebin.com/Rdt8aZP6

Comment: I accepted you as the answer, but can you please update your post showing that I needed to change the build to full release to get this working?